# Matriz identidad ERROR!

Tags: java

He hecho la siguiente función para comprobar si una matriz es identidad o no, pero hay algunos casos en los que no acierta, y muestra como identidad una matriz que realmente no lo es:

```
public static boolean esIdentidad (int[][] matriz) {
    boolean identidad = true;
    
    for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.length; fila++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matriz[fila].length; col++) {
            if (fila==col)
                if (matriz[fila][col] == 1)
                    identidad = true;
                else
                    identidad = false;
            else
                if (matriz[fila][col] == 0)
                    identidad = true;
                else
                    identidad = false;
        }
    }
    return identidad;
}
```

La comprobación ha sido hecha con las siguientes matrices:

```
    int[][] m1 = {  {1,0,0,0},
                    {0,1,0,0},
                    {0,0,1,0},
                    {0,0,0,1}};
    
    int[][] m2 = {  {1,0,0,0},
                    {0,1,0,0},
                    {0,0,1,1},
                    {0,0,0,1}};
```

En ambos casos da como resultado "True", cuando realmente debería mostrar primero "True" y segundo "False".

¿Por qué falla el código?

Comment: Si en cada vuelta del bucle usas la misma variable que en cada vuelta se va machacando con un valor nuevo, la única iteración que realmente te da el resultado es la última. El resto te sobran.

Comment: No entendí muy bien en comentario! Podría aclarármelo un poco más?

Comment: Que en cada vuelta de tu bucle for, vas comprobando una posición de la matriz y posicionas la variable del resultado identidad a true o false. Pero luego vuelves a iterar otra vez en el bucle y vuelves a posicionar identidad con otro valor, y luego otra vez y al final cuando el bucle termina, el último valor que tenga identidad es el que retornas. Todo lo que has hecho en las vueltas del for hasta la última da igual porque el valor de identidad que retornas es el último.

Comment: Te recomiendo que solo verifiques cuando las condiciones de una matriz identidad no se cumplan, por ejemplo, cuando `fila == col`, si `matriz[fila][col] != 1` entonces `identidad = false`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que de verdad vas complicándote con tantos `if else if else` ...

Simplificando las clausulas si hay algo distinto de `1` en la diagonal principal y también cuando haya algún valor distinto de `0` en cualquier otra posición del *array* (*fuera de la diag. ppal.*) que se dispare un `false`, naturalmente ya no se trataría de una Matriz Identidad, caso contrario cuando se alcance el fin de los ciclos:

```
public static boolean esIdentidad (int[][] matriz) {
  for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.length; fila++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < matriz[fila].length; col++) {
      if(i==j && matriz[fila][col]!=1){
        return false;
      }

      if(i!=j && matriz[fila][col]!=0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Las variables `i` y `j` no están declaradas